# Make debian "apt" (new apt-get / aptitude frontend) cache .deb files in '/var/cache/apt/archives/'

Tags: debian, apt, cache, aptitude

On a current (2018-06) Debian sid, installing .deb packages via `apt-get` or `aptitude` or `synaptic` caches the downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`:

```
# rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/nano_*
# aptitude install nano
  [...]
# aptitude purge nano
  [...]
# ls /var/cache/apt/archives/nano_*

/var/cache/apt/archives/nano_2.9.7-1_amd64.deb
```

Using the frontend `apt` does not cache the downloaded files anymore:

```
# rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/nano_*
# apt install nano
  [...]
# ls /var/cache/apt/archives/nano_*
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/nano_*':
      No such file or directory
```

So switching between two mutually exclusive sets of packages re-downloads everything. How can I change the settings of `apt` to keep the downloaded files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs` file with the following content:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
```

Your `*.deb` should be kept in `/var/cache/apt/archives/*` directory.

Or use it as option to keep the debs files for some selected packages.

```
 apt -o APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages="true" install some_package.
```

Comment: Thank you. And FTR, this is option is not documented in the man-page for `apt.conf`, `apt-config` or `apt_preferences`.

Comment: Thanks! The ready-to-copy-paste version could be `echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' | tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-custom-local` or if you need `sudo` then `echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-custom-local`

Comment: @GAD3R Can we have `apt` to cache those `.deb` files in a custom folder, say, `~/localrepo` instead of `/var/cache/apt/archives/`?

Comment: if used in docker image, should truncate `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean`